# Save results as certain variables after certain characters

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a set of results that I've extracted from a database and cleaned up using regex: 
AOC/BEA/TA/MMSC/T/ACCTT/ACCTESC/T/SRTTA/TA/

Now each letter combination is a product ID.

I need to save each ID as a separate variable to then echo later in the page.

Example:

```
$Link1 = AOC/
$Link2 = BEA/
$Link3 = TA/
```

The PHP to get the ID is:

```
$History = $DataRow["ProductID"];

$HistoryEdit =  ereg_replace("[^A-Z\/]", "", $History); 

echo $HistoryEdit;
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array rather than separate variables:

```
$Links = explode('/', $HistoryEdit);
```

Now:

```
$Links[0] = "AOC";
$Links[1] = "BEA";
$Links[2] = "TA";
```

and so on.